# FMDB in OSX Swift project -> Many errors

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, xcode6, fmdb

I've added FMDB in my Swift project and followed the FMDB Swift instructions (i.e. copy relevant .h/m. files and create the bridging header incl. import statement). When I try to compile I get a truckload of errors, all of them Apple Match-O-Linker errors...

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_sqlite3_bind_blob", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase bindObject:toColumn:inStatement:] in FMDatabase.o
  "_sqlite3_bind_double", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase bindObject:toColumn:inStatement:] in FMDatabase.o
  "_sqlite3_bind_int", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase bindObject:toColumn:inStatement:] in FMDatabase.o
  "_sqlite3_bind_int64", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase bindObject:toColumn:inStatement:] in FMDatabase.o
  "_sqlite3_bind_null", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase bindObject:toColumn:inStatement:] in FMDatabase.o
  "_sqlite3_bind_parameter_count", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase executeQuery:withArgumentsInArray:orDictionary:orVAList:] in FMDatabase.o
      -[FMDatabase executeUpdate:error:withArgumentsInArray:orDictionary:orVAList:] in FMDatabase.o
  "_sqlite3_bind_parameter_index", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase executeQuery:withArgumentsInArray:orDictionary:orVAList:] in FMDatabase.o
      -[FMDatabase executeUpdate:error:withArgumentsInArray:orDictionary:orVAList:] in FMDatabase.o
  "_sqlite3_bind_text", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase bindObject:toColumn:inStatement:] in FMDatabase.o
  "_sqlite3_busy_handler", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase setMaxBusyRetryTimeInterval:] in FMDatabase.o
  "_sqlite3_changes", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase changes] in FMDatabase.o
  "_sqlite3_close", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase close] in FMDatabase.o
  "_sqlite3_column_blob", referenced from:
      -[FMResultSet dataForColumnIndex:] in FMResultSet.o
      -[FMResultSet dataNoCopyForColumnIndex:] in FMResultSet.o
  "_sqlite3_column_bytes", referenced from:
      -[FMResultSet dataForColumnIndex:] in FMResultSet.o
      -[FMResultSet dataNoCopyForColumnIndex:] in FMResultSet.o
  "_sqlite3_column_count", referenced from:
      -[FMResultSet columnCount] in FMResultSet.o
      -[FMResultSet columnNameToIndexMap] in FMResultSet.o
      -[FMResultSet kvcMagic:] in FMResultSet.o
      -[FMResultSet resultDictionary] in FMResultSet.o
  "_sqlite3_column_double", referenced from:
      -[FMResultSet doubleForColumnIndex:] in FMResultSet.o
  "_sqlite3_column_int", referenced from:
      -[FMResultSet intForColumnIndex:] in FMResultSet.o
  "_sqlite3_column_int64", referenced from:
      -[FMResultSet longForColumnIndex:] in FMResultSet.o
      -[FMResultSet longLongIntForColumnIndex:] in FMResultSet.o
  "_sqlite3_column_name", referenced from:
      -[FMResultSet columnNameToIndexMap] in FMResultSet.o
      -[FMResultSet kvcMagic:] in FMResultSet.o
      -[FMResultSet resultDictionary] in FMResultSet.o
      -[FMResultSet columnNameForIndex:] in FMResultSet.o
  "_sqlite3_column_text", referenced from:
      -[FMResultSet kvcMagic:] in FMResultSet.o
      -[FMResultSet stringForColumnIndex:] in FMResultSet.o
      -[FMResultSet UTF8StringForColumnIndex:] in FMResultSet.o
  "_sqlite3_column_type", referenced from:
      -[FMResultSet stringForColumnIndex:] in FMResultSet.o
      -[FMResultSet dateForColumnIndex:] in FMResultSet.o
      -[FMResultSet dataForColumnIndex:] in FMResultSet.o
      -[FMResultSet dataNoCopyForColumnIndex:] in FMResultSet.o
      -[FMResultSet columnIndexIsNull:] in FMResultSet.o
      -[FMResultSet UTF8StringForColumnIndex:] in FMResultSet.o
      -[FMResultSet objectForColumnIndex:] in FMResultSet.o
      ...
  "_sqlite3_create_function", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase makeFunctionNamed:maximumArguments:withBlock:] in FMDatabase.o
  "_sqlite3_data_count", referenced from:
      -[FMResultSet resultDict] in FMResultSet.o
      -[FMResultSet resultDictionary] in FMResultSet.o
  "_sqlite3_errcode", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase lastErrorCode] in FMDatabase.o
      -[FMDatabase errorWithMessage:] in FMDatabase.o
      -[FMResultSet hasAnotherRow] in FMResultSet.o
  "_sqlite3_errmsg", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase lastErrorMessage] in FMDatabase.o
      -[FMDatabase executeUpdate:error:withArgumentsInArray:orDictionary:orVAList:] in FMDatabase.o
      -[FMResultSet nextWithError:] in FMResultSet.o
  "_sqlite3_exec", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase executeStatements:withResultBlock:] in FMDatabase.o
  "_sqlite3_finalize", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase close] in FMDatabase.o
      -[FMDatabase executeQuery:withArgumentsInArray:orDictionary:orVAList:] in FMDatabase.o
      -[FMDatabase executeUpdate:error:withArgumentsInArray:orDictionary:orVAList:] in FMDatabase.o
      -[FMStatement close] in FMDatabase.o
      -[FMDatabase(FMDatabaseAdditions) validateSQL:error:] in FMDatabaseAdditions.o
  "_sqlite3_free", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase executeStatements:withResultBlock:] in FMDatabase.o
  "_sqlite3_last_insert_rowid", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase lastInsertRowId] in FMDatabase.o
  "_sqlite3_libversion", referenced from:
      +[FMDatabase sqliteLibVersion] in FMDatabase.o
  "_sqlite3_next_stmt", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase close] in FMDatabase.o
  "_sqlite3_open", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase open] in FMDatabase.o
  "_sqlite3_open_v2", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase openWithFlags:] in FMDatabase.o
  "_sqlite3_prepare_v2", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase executeQuery:withArgumentsInArray:orDictionary:orVAList:] in FMDatabase.o
      -[FMDatabase executeUpdate:error:withArgumentsInArray:orDictionary:orVAList:] in FMDatabase.o
      -[FMDatabase(FMDatabaseAdditions) validateSQL:error:] in FMDatabaseAdditions.o
  "_sqlite3_reset", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase executeUpdate:error:withArgumentsInArray:orDictionary:orVAList:] in FMDatabase.o
      -[FMStatement reset] in FMDatabase.o
  "_sqlite3_sleep", referenced from:
      _FMDBDatabaseBusyHandler in FMDatabase.o
  "_sqlite3_step", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase executeUpdate:error:withArgumentsInArray:orDictionary:orVAList:] in FMDatabase.o
      -[FMResultSet nextWithError:] in FMResultSet.o
  "_sqlite3_threadsafe", referenced from:
      -[FMDatabase initWithPath:] in FMDatabase.o
      +[FMDatabase isSQLiteThreadSafe] in FMDatabase.o
  "_sqlite3_user_data", referenced from:
      _FMDBBlockSQLiteCallBackFunction in FMDatabase.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The FMDB files I've added are:

```
FMDatabase.h
FMDatabase.m
FMDatabaseAdditions.h
FMDatabaseAdditions.m
FMDatabasePool.h
FMDatabasePool.m
FMDatabaseQueue.h
FMDatabaseQueue.m
FMDB.h
FMResultSet.h
FMResultSet.m
```

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Nevermind anyone! I solved it. I had to link libsqlite3.dylib into my project via the Build Phases page in the project settings. There was no framework group so far in my project so it was a bit confusing.

Comment: And if you deleted it, like I did, then go to the Trash and restore it using Put Back. You may have to close Xcode and reopen it.

Answer (score 0):

Your project -> General -> Linked Framework and Libraries you can add this libsqlite3.0.tbd.
Now can you build your project and framework.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this error infomation like this:

```
    Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error Group
    "_sqlite3_column_type", referenced from:
    "_sqlite3_column_double", referenced from:
    "_sqlite3_column_int", referenced from:
    "_sqlite3_column_blob", referenced from:
    "_sqlite3_data_count", referenced from:
    "_sqlite3_column_count", referenced from:
    "_sqlite3_create_function", referenced from:
    "_sqlite3_user_data", referenced from:
    "_sqlite3_exec", referenced from:
    "_sqlite3_step", referenced from:
    "_sqlite3_prepare_v2", referenced from:
    "_sqlite3_threadsafe", referenced from:
    "_sqlite3_bind_null", referenced from:
    "_sqlite3_column_name", referenced from:
    "_sqlite3_errcode", referenced from:
    "_sqlite3_bind_int", referenced from:
    "_sqlite3_free", referenced from:
    "_sqlite3_bind_int64", referenced from:
    "_sqlite3_open", referenced from:
    "_sqlite3_last_insert_rowid", referenced from:
    "_sqlite3_column_bytes", referenced from:
    "_sqlite3_bind_parameter_index", referenced from:
    "_sqlite3_bind_blob", referenced from:
    "_sqlite3_column_text", referenced from:
    "_sqlite3_finalize", referenced from:
    "_sqlite3_errmsg", referenced from:
    "_sqlite3_busy_handler", referenced from:
    "_sqlite3_reset", referenced from:
    "_sqlite3_changes", referenced from:
    "_sqlite3_open_v2", referenced from:
    "_sqlite3_column_int64", referenced from:
    "_sqlite3_next_stmt", referenced from:
    "_sqlite3_bind_text", referenced from:
    "_sqlite3_libversion", referenced from:
    "_sqlite3_bind_parameter_count", referenced from:
    "_sqlite3_bind_double", referenced from:
    "_sqlite3_sleep", referenced from:
    "_sqlite3_close", referenced from:

    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Go to Your project -> General -> Linked Framework and Libraries you can add this libsqlite3.0.tbd. Now can you build your project and framework.